# Is it possible to reference prototype page from another prototype page in Hippo CMS?

Tags: reference, components, prototype, abstract, hippocms

I have one abstract page, and prototype page that references it using **hst:referencecomponent** and adds one component to it. Now I want to create one more prototype page, and reference prototype page I created earlier. But when I try to create a new page using this newly created prototype page, I get error *"[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 05.07.2015 16:58:56 WARN  http-nio-8080-exec-6 [HstComponentConfigurationService.populateComponentReferences:860] Cannot lookup referenced component 'hst:prototypepages/kkb.prototype.base' for this component ['hst:pages/investor-relations-kkb.prototype.base.plus']. We skip this reference"*

So can one prototype page reference another prototype page, or I must create a lot of similar abstract pages, then reference them in prototype pages one by one?

Answer (score 0):

I've give it a try and this is possible to reference a prototype page from another prototype page using the **hst:referencecomponent** attribute. Also looking at the CND this is coherent.

It seems looking at the stacktrace that you have created the second page that reference the first one in **hst:pages** but prototypes pages must be declared in **hst:prototypepages**

Can you try again to declare *kkb.prototype.base.plus* in the **hst:prototypepages** folder of the configuration?

Comment: In console, I have 2 prototype pages, first one references abstract page, second one references first prototype page.<br/>
Problem occurs when I create page using cms, not console, choosing prototype page as page template. When I do that, in _hst:workspace/hst:pages _ my newly created page appears, and reference abstract page that referenced by prototype page that I choose. There is no problem. But when I choose prototype page that references another prototype page as template, I get error.

Comment: Seems like created pages can reference only one level of inheritance of prototype pages, that directly reference to abstract page, and can't obtain abstract page if it's references through another prototype page.

Comment: Ah I see it now. This needs to be investigated @Hippo to check if it's a bug or an intentional limitation. In the meantime I can only say that you'll have to use a workaround.